# Mysql search string

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a search box that will search for a keyword in the **field** : `description`
then return results. its done in mysql and php.
the description can go from 10 to 600 characters long. I would like to return only a part of result.
for **example** :
 I am searching for the keyword= John
instead of displaying the whole **field** `description` as the result I want to see the sentence where the keyword is found only: ... Hello my name is john and I ...
not the whole paragraph.

I can use sql or php whichever one is better. I tried substring but failed implementing it any example would be great.

```sql
SELECT  SUBSTR(description,2,100)  
FROM screenplays 
WHERE lower(description) like '% $search_word_fix %'
```

Comment: Take a look at Full-Text Search Functions - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: I heard the fulltext functions isn't that great. my hosting company told me so. I ve never really used it so I am not sure why

Comment: Please make the title of your question more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use php.. I had written a function few months back. It searches for keywords in a text and returns a string with 'bold' keywords. Hope this helps.

```
    $str = 'I have a search box that will search for a keyword in the field : description then return results. its done in mysql and php. the description can go from 10 to 600 characters long. I would like to return only a part of result. for example : I am searching for the keyword= John instead of displaying the whole field description as the result I want to see the sentence where the keyword is found only: ... Hello my name is john and I ... not the whole paragraph.

    I can use sql or php whichever one is better. I tried substring but failed implementing it any example would be great.';
    $search = array();
    $search[] = "example";
    echo descriptionSearch($str,$search);
    function descriptionSearch($desc,$words,$max_number_words = 30)
    {
                $descs = explode(" ",$desc);
                $positions = array();
                $i = 0;
                foreach($words as $w)
                {
                    $j = 0;
                    foreach($descs as $d)
                    {
                        $w = strtolower(trim($w));
                        $d = strtolower(trim($d));
                        if(strpos($d,$w) !== false)
                        {
                            $positions[] = $j;
                            $descs[$j] = str_replace($w,"<span style='font-weight: bold;'>".$d."</span>",$d);
                        }
                $j++;
            }
            $i++;
        }
        $max = 0;
        if(sizeof($positions) > 0)
        {
            foreach($positions as $j)
            {
                if($max < 4)
                {
                    $i = $j -5;
                    if($i < 0)
                    {
                        $i = 0;
                    }
                    while($i < ($j+10))
                    {
                        $toreturn .= $descs[$i]." ";
                        $i++;
                    }
                    $toreturn .=  " ...";
                    $max++;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for($i=0; $i < $max_number_words; $i++)
            {
                $toreturn .=  $descs[$i]." ";
            }
        }
        return $toreturn;
    }
```

Comment: hey Shoogle, what if I send a 2 keyword search like 
"hello world' ? I tried it it wouldn't highlight any of the words

Comment: Yh unfortunately this function was not written for it. I can write a function that will help, if you can wait few hours.

Comment: sure thing I've been trying to do it myself I failed so far, thank you Shoogle.  $search = array(); $search[] = "keyword"; search is an array I thought it would work but I think not.

Comment: Check the new answer. Hope that helps. I might review it, but it should work fine

Answer (score 2):

I thought by query, it will hamper performance. Because of string calculations. So I have done this by php substr function logic.

```
SELECT  description 
        FROM screenplays 
        WHERE lower(description) like '% $search_word_fix %'

//$description will have longer string.
//$short_string will have shorter string.

    $short_string=get_less_string($description,'john',20);

    function get_less_string($string,$key,$num){
             $desc=explode($key,$string);
             $left='...'.substr($desc[0], strlen($desc[0])-$num,$num);
             $right=substr($desc[1],0,$num).'...';
             $final_string=$left.$key.$right;
             return $final_string;
        }
```

Comment: MySQL does case-insensitive searches, so you might want to change the first line in the function to compare the lower-case version of the key and the string. Otherwise, a search for "test" won't find the word "Test" in the results.

Comment: $search_word_fix should be in lower case before operations... @pbarney

Comment: That won't matter if $description isn't also in lower case, which I can't imagine anybody would want. It's just simpler to do `$desc = explode(strtolower($key),strtolower($string));` In any case, it's a very handy function and I'm making good use of it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You CAN do it either way, and both will be about as efficient.  PHP is probably a better more flexible solution, but just for kicks I tried to do it in MySQL, to see how it would work

```
SELECT SUBSTR(
          description,
          if(INSTR(description, '$search_word_fix') - 10 < 0,
             0,
             (INSTR(description, '$search_word_fix') - 10)),
          if(
             INSTR(description, '$search_word_fix') + 10 >
                length(description),
             length(description),
             NSTR(description, '$search_word_fix') + 10))
  FROM screenplays
 WHERE lower(description) LIKE '% $search_word_fix %'
```

Comment: really great way, just want to ask one thing, the question is about performance, which is much faster this way or php way, i don't know about performance that's why i ask

Comment: @jogesh_p - I don't have any benchmarks.  Your biggest performance hit is going to be WHERE lower(description) LIKE '% $search_word_fix %'  That's going to be several orders of magnitude more expensive to process then anything else you're likely to do on anything more than a trivial table.

Answer (score 1):

Modified answer, This can search better. In this example. I am searching for 'for example' or 'john'

```
        $str = 'I have a search box that will search for a keyword in the field : description then return results. its done in mysql and php. the description can go from 10 to 600 characters long. I would like to return only a part of result. for example : I am searching for the keyword= John instead of displaying the whole field description as the result I want to see the sentence where the keyword is found only: ... Hello my name is john and I ... not the whole paragraph.

            I can use sql or php whichever one is better. I tried substring but failed implementing it any example would be great.';
        $search = array();
        $search[] = "for example";
        $search[] = "john";
        echo descriptionSearch($str,$search);
        function descriptionSearch($desc,$words,$max_number_words = 30)
        {
            $positions = array();
            $i = 0;
            foreach($words as $w)
            {
                    $w = strtolower(trim($w));
                    $d = strtolower(trim($d));
                    if(strpos($desc,$w) !== false)
                    {
                        $positions[] = strpos($desc,$w);
                        $desc = str_replace($w,"<span style='font-weight: bold;'>".substr($desc,strpos($desc,$w),strlen($w))."</span>",$desc);
                    }
                $i++;
            }
            $max = 0;
            if(sizeof($positions) > 0)
            {
                foreach($positions as $j)
                {
                    if($max < 4)
                    {
                        $i = $j -16;
                        if($i < 0)
                        {
                            $i = 0;
                        }
                            $toreturn .= substr($desc,$i,80);
                        $toreturn .=  " ...";
                        $max++;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
            $descs = explode(" ",$desc);
                for($i=0; $i < $max_number_words; $i++)
                {
                    $toreturn .=  $descs[$i]." ";
                }
            }
            return $toreturn;
        }
```

Comment: Search array is usually an explode for the search term. for example: $search = explode(" ","Hello world");

Comment: I added a 3rd word it actually repeated john result. for 2 words it seems it works thanks Shoogle